# aws target response time of alb become increase and unstable when target group moved to pods in eks from EC2 instances

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-ec2, amazon-elb

I try to migrate rails server that running directly on EC2 instance to EKS pod.

The server runs with unicorn_rails that has 20+ worker, also it has nginx as frontend that receive requests and communicate with unicorn_rails via unix domain socket.

When it run directly on EC2 isntance and ALB with target group of these instances, latency always < 500ms and fluctuation range was only ±10 ms

But when it runs as pod on EKS, latency increases nearly a hundreds ms on average and fluctuation range become ±100 ms, even if it receives only a few request per second per pod. (for EKS nodepool, using same instance type of ec2 version)

Is it common for the latency of a request sent from alb to an eks pod to be this large or unstable compared to a request sent to an ec2 instances, even if request flow is nearly same?

belows are details of migration.

To migrate this server to eks pod, I use following 2 containers

1. unicorn_rails with single worker of it
2. nginx as sidecar container of 1, receives requests from alb

container 1 and 2 communicate with unix domain socket like EC2 instance version of the server does.

I believe request flow nearly same between ec2 version and eks version, so cannot figure out why latency behavior is so different.

```
old: alb =(network)=> EC2 (nginx) =(unix domain socket)=> EC2 (unicorn rails worker)
new: alb =(network)=> EKS pod (nginx) =(unix domain socket)=> EKS pod (unicorn rails worker)
```

reducing unicorn_rails worker is critical? or kube-proxy adds overhead?

any thoughts?

Comment: Some questions 
- did you use the same EC2 instance types in both cases?
- did you use an Ingress Controller or is your nginx an "LoadBalancer" ingress type?
- do you have a CPU resource limits defined in the pod or maybe a quota on namespace level? Could you verify that your pod is not throttled?

Comment: hi, thank you for your response, A1. yes, we use c5.4xlarge for both case.
A2 we let aws load balancer controller to create alb from our ingress resource.
A3 no, we don't set CPU limits to pod or namespace. I'm not sure what 'throttled' exactly mean, but based on ps or top output, unicorn_rails worker and nginx's CPU usage seems to be enough small (<30%)